# Is there any good summary, lecture notes, textbook or videos that give overview of firm-level productivity models?

Tags: reference-request, applied-econometrics, productivity

As the title says, I am looking for some tutorials/educational materials for firm-level productivity models.

I am looking for some source that would cover the most commonly used models. Also, it is a plus if the source is written on a beginner/intermediate level that does not assume much prior knowledge from the reader.